# How to run powershell script in maven

Tags: maven, powershell

I currently dealing with a problem using maven. I try to update a file when building the software using maven. For some reason, I have to use a powershell script and run it when building using mvn. Here is my code:

```
<exec executable="powershell.exe"
                      spawn="true">
                    <arg value="/c"/>
                    <arg value="myReplace.ps1"/>
                    <arg value="../../the/path/to/the/directory/" />
                    <arg value ="filename"/>
                    <arg value="value1" />
                    <arg value="value2" />
                    <arg value="value3" />
             </exec>
```

It does not work as expected, can someone help me?

Comment: please give us the error message

Comment: This looks a lot like Ant. You said (and tagged Maven). How is that? Don't you just want to use the [Exec Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This message dates from a while but I went through the exercise in the last days. The key is to use the exec plugin as stated. Here is an example in a project's pom.xml:

The code below launches the code-signing on a PowerShell module script. Note that the command string must begin, for calling PowerShell functions from the command line, with & which is not properly digested by Maven. Escaping it does the trick. For more complex operations, call a PS script.

```
...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>scripts-package</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                <!-- optional -->
                    <workingDirectory>/Temp</workingDirectory>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-command</argument>
                        <argument>"&amp; { Set-AuthenticodeSignature '${project.build.directory}/Logging_Functions/*.psm1' @(Get-ChildItem ${project.build.certificate.path} -codesigning)[0]"}</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

Answer (score 0):

This avoids a [bug](https://github.com/mojohaus/exec-maven-plugin/issues/48) with PowerShell hanging on StdIn.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <useMavenLogger>true</useMavenLogger>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>run-my-script</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>powershell.exe</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-InputFormat</argument>
                            <argument>None</argument>
                            <argument>-File</argument>
                            <argument>${basedir}/my_script.ps1</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            <executions>
        <plugin>
```